# Объединить страницу корзины и оформить заказ Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пытаюсь объединить на одной странице корзину и оформление заказа, но столкнулся с проблемой, что WP не дает в админке поменять страницу корзины на страницу оформление заказа, не ищет ничего, кроме корзины.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто подсказать, как это обойти? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Средствами WooCommerce сделать этого нельзя.

Comment: Подскажите, есть ли какой то выход ? Надо писать свою логику или лучше полностью уйти от данной реализации ?

Comment: Я бы советовал полностью уйти от такого подхода.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду переубеждать клиента!

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант поставить редирект с корзины на чекаут

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout_if_cart' );
function redirect_to_checkout_if_cart() {
    
    if ( !is_cart() ) return;

    global $woocommerce;

    wp_redirect( $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url(), 302 );
    
    exit;
}
```

Потом привести шаблон  woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php к нужным функциям из шаблона корзины woocommerce/cart/cart.php